# SSIS ExecuteSQL task error with ResultSet

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2012

Hi I am trying to return a ResultSet from an "Execute SQL Task" in SSIS.
I am then trying to save the result in a "ResultSet" variable.
My Query works in the console and my connection is ok to.

Here is my Query
**SELECT Src FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable] group by Src**

**Src is nvarchar(255)**

When I execute the task I am getting following error
**[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "SELECT Src
  FROM [myDB].[dbo].[myTable..." failed with the following error: "The type of the value (DBNull) being assigned to variable "User::ResultSet" differs from the current variable type (String). Variables may not change type during execution. Variable types are strict, except for variables of type Object.
". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.**
I am also attaching the screen shots for the Task setup.

Please help.
[ExecuteSQL Screen1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BLGr.jpg)

[ExecuteSQL Screen2 - ResultSet setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9q5Z.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

[In SSIS 2012](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/742282/ssis-2012-wont-assign-null-values-from-sql-queries-to-variables-of-type-string-inside-a-foreach-loop) within a ForEach loop using an ADO enumerator, you are unable to assign a null value to a variable of type String when the source value came from a SQL query returning a null value.

I would suggest Derived Column Transform feature of SSIS 
you'll use the SSIS ISNULL function to detect the NULL value - and then do something with it.

[More info about Derived Column Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069.aspx)

For example transforming String column:

**ISNULL([String-Column]) ? "There Was No Value" : [String-Column]**

Comment: I am getting the error at the "Execute SQL" part so not even touch the ForEach Loop.

Comment: Also, I have tried modifying my query to use isNULL(src,0) but still getting the same message.

Comment: I think 0 will try to put integer 0 in the column. Have you tried putting some text or " " ?